# How to change timezone in selenium/standalone-chrome-debug container

Tags: docker, selenium

By default, the selenium/standalone-chrome-debug container runs in the UTC timezone. I want to set the container timezone to    AEST — Australian Eastern Standard Time. Would you please help?

Comment: Are you using it with Java ?

Comment: cruisepandey,I'm using it with c#

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time zone with the environment variable `TZ`. In your case:

```bash
docker run -it selenium/node-chrome-debug -e "TZ=Australia/Sydney"
```

see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Setting-a-Timezone